# Neural network model prediction in Keras without using GPU

Tags: neural-network, gpu, theano, pickle, keras

My neural networks model was built in Keras over Theano using a GPU.
I am storing it using Pickle for future use, possibly on another computer.

Is it possible to use the model for prediction without a GPU?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. It's even a common use-case. GPUs help boost training, but sometimes aren't available in production (for example, if you run on a customer's phone).

I don't know Theano much, but they might have an equivalent to `tensorflow.serving`. You can always serialize the trained Model object and read it from the other machine.

To serialize, you can either use:

- The built-in `keras.models.save_model` and `keras.models.load_model` that dumps Models to hdf5 files.
- If you need/prefer pickle - it's basically not supported by Keras, but you can use this trick - http://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html